# Django ModelForm in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i have got a question.Im new in Django and lear it since 3 weeks. I need to develop a Cookie Popup with optin for a project at University.
My Question is. I develop it in Django python. In the backend i have services that collect all Cookie Information and pass it in a Cookie Model. So now i have the Cookie model and need to pass it as context in the view. For the moment i see all the Cookies that the services collects in Browser. But i need to validate if the typ is Esential or Marketing and seperate this in the collapse in template. How i can do this ? My idea is to validate it in the template
with this line

```
 {% if cookie.typ == 'Essenziell' %}
```

and if the typ is Essenziell i show this in the collapse.

View.py

```
def optin(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CookieForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect
else:

    form = CookieForm
    cookie_list = Cookie.objects.all()

    context_dict = {'form': form, 'cookie_list': cookie_list}
    template = 'cookies/cookie.html'

return render(request, template,
    context_dict
              )
```

This is a part of the Template

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Marketing" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Marketing">
        Marketing
        </button>


        <div class="collapse" id="Essenziell">
        <div class="card card-body">
            {% for cookie in cookie_list  %}
                {% if cookie.typ == 'Essenziell' %}
                    <p>{{ cookie.cookie }}</p>
                    <p>{{ cookie.provider }}</p>
                    <p>{{ cookie.description }}</p>
                    <p>{{ cookie.typ }}</p>
                    <p>{{ cookie.runTime }}</p>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        </div>
```

Model.py

```
class Cookie(models.Model):
"""
:cookie: The defined name of the Cookie
:provider: Who will set this Cookie ex. Google, Matomo, Shopprovider
:description: The description of the seted Cookie
:cookieRuntime: The lifetime of the Cookie
:typ: Type of the Cookie
"""


cookie = models.CharField(max_length=50)
provider = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
typ = models.ForeignKey(Typ)
```

form.py

```
class CookieForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Cookie
    field = {
        'cookie',
        'provider',
        'description',
        'typ',         
    }
```

Comment: If i pass the Modelform as context to template why i cant access the value in my model throw the modelform? I thought i can use form.cookie.value but it doesnt work hmm

Answer (score 1):

Why i need Serializer ? I dont know the reason why i should use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Serializers` for validation and stuff. Read this:

> https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/